# I need to build in offline HTML form for completion with a button the print the data in a table

Tags: html, forms, offline

I am looking to build an **'easy on the eye'** offline form which will be saved locally on users machines.

The purpose of the form is to record information and minutes taken in a meeting.

The form will include a logo, a header, hopefully some a dividing strip (preferably blue) and fields to complete in a table

- Date
- Time
- Location
- Attendees
- An expanding (Downwards) text box with gets bigger when you type enough to fill it.
- A print button which gives you the option of saving as a PDF or actually print it.

I have trawled the internet and even tried to adapt source codes on forms I like the look of but I'm not confident that even when I have adapted the code that those forms still don't have have some kind of connection to the internet as the information recorded in the forms will be highly confidential.

Can you point me in the direction or give me some pointers?
I have seen tutorials but the forms look very basic.

Many Thanks

Comment: Why do you need an HTML form? It sounds like you could do all of that in Word and save yourself a headache.

Comment: For these specific requirements, you'll need to study HTML, CSS & JS. You can find great tutorials at http://w3schools.com and complete references at http://developer.mozilla.org . Also, good luck at creating a PDF document. Unless you find a framework for that, you'll need to build it byte by byte. (You could only have an option to print, since you can "print to PDF", though)

Comment: It's a personal project Tom. If I can get it to work I would like to roll it out to colleagues